# Program throw wrong output in php?

Tags: php

this code is to sum up 1 to 10 using the arithmetic progression

The output should be as
550
code:

```
<?php
        $total = 0;
        for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
            for ($j = 10; $j >=1 ; $j++) {
                $total =  $i + $j;
                break;
            } 
        } 
        $total = $total / 2;
        print $total."<br/>";
?>
```

Current output: 10
Expected output: 550

and In second case I have

```
<?php
    $list = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    foreach ($list as $row) 
    {
        switch ($row) 
        {
            case 1:
                print "This is One\n";
            case 2:
                print "This is Two\n";
            case 3:
                print "This is Three\n";
        }
    }
    print "\n\n";
?>
```

Current output:
This is One 
This is Two 
This is Three 
This is Two 
This is Three 
This is Three

Expected output: 
This is One 
This is Two 
This is Three 
This is Four

In my first code I want to get 550 through first program but when I run it throw wrong output i.e 122666133 and in case of second program current program throw wrong output but expected output as I mention above. So, How can I fix this issue ?Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: Second code you're not break in the cases and there's no case for four

Comment: I don't see any throwing happening?

Comment: In your first program, are you sure you want $total += $total... ?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve by `$total += $total + $i + $j;` and `$total .= $total / 2;`. `$j` is always be `10`, why loop then?

Comment: First program `$total .= $total / 2;` concatenation `"1"."1"` is not `2` it's `11`, second program as @Alfabravo said. no `break;` and no `case 4:`

Comment: I have edit in my first program but now output is 10

Comment: `$total =  $i + $j;`  you overwrite total each time `$total +=  $i + $j;`  see https://3v4l.org/XdHXV

Comment: I have mention question above the first program. what I actually want.

Comment: Your variable j is always 10. You do not need second for loop to sum numbers between 1-10. Beside that sum of first 10 numbers is 55 not 550.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Please check Below Code: 
    <?php
        $list = [1, 2, 3, 4];
        foreach ($list as $row) 
        {
            switch ($row) 
            {
                case 1:
                    print "This is One\n";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    print "This is Two\n";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    print "This is Three\n";
                    break;
                default:
                    print "This is Four\n";
                    break;
            }
        }
        print "\n\n";
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: Since you changed your question, can you explain what are you trying to do at first question?

In the first question try to use *+=* instead of concetenation. You are simply adding *10 + i* at each step to your *total* variable. The sum should be 110. Then you divide it by 2. So expected result is 55. I suggest you to use some print statements inside or outside of *for* loops to see the mistake.

Second question is already answered properly.